# Using first available in an IP Address Block

Tags: networking, ip

what does it mean when a network admin says to use the first # in the address block of 226?   And he gives me the below information:

```
IP’s: 204.68.134.226-.231
Mask: 255.255.255.0
GW: 204.68.134.254
```

Does it mean that I should use 204.68.134.227 to put into my computer?

Answer (score 4):

With a 255.255.255.0 subnet mask, any address 204.68.134.1 - 204.68.134.254 are valid addresses, 204.68.134.0 will be the network address and 204.68.135.255 will be the broadcast address, so I'm guessing he means to use 204.68.134.226 although I would go back to him because if that's what he meant he should have just said so.

Edit: He may mean to check if any of the addresses in the range you specified are already in use, and if so to then use the next one.

Comment: I was thinking that he meant to use .227, but this would not be the case?

Comment: @Joe Not with a mask of `255.255.255.0`, no.

Comment: @Joe Why would you skip .226?

Comment: @Joe's admin is being obtuse and Joe made an innocent mistake. Joe is probably thinking of the rule "[Don't use the first or last IP address in an IP range](http://www.inetdaemon.com/tutorials/internet/ip/whatis_ip_network.shtml)", but that rule doesn't apply to this scenario, since he has been allocated a subset of addresses within the  204.68.134.0/24 subnet. An easy mistake for someone who isn't a network administrator. The admin could have been more clear.